# How to set variable in `case`?

Tags: bash, shell

I met an error, not sure what's going wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
aa="boy"
cc="1"
case $cc in
    [1]* ) echo "You input 1";; aa="girl";;
    * ) echo "Please answer 1";;
esac
```

Error:

```
./myscript: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
./myscript: line 5: `    [1]* ) echo "You input 1";; aa="girl";;'
```

Comment: `[1]* ) echo "You input 1"; aa="girl";;` (only one semicolon between commands!)

Comment: OOPS I see, Thank you. I am sitting in front of my computer too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this,

```
#!/bin/bash
aa="boy"
case $1 in
    [1]* )
        echo "You input 1"
        aa="girl"
        ;;
    * ) ;;
esac
echo $aa
```

Output is

```
$ ./test.sh
boy
$ ./test.sh 1
You input 1
girl
```

Answer (score 1):

Ending of case pattern should be one time so you have to use ;; only once for every pattern.

```
[1]* ) echo "You input 1"; aa="girl";;
```

You can change the line like shown.